Is there a way to change text colors in pgAdmin 4 v4.8.6?
I'd like to change the comment text in the Query Tool window from the current rust/brown to green.
"Creating pgAdmin Themes" did not work, as the directory does not exist for me.
"Change font colour and type in PgAdmin 8.2 / 9.1" is not great because it changes the desktop background colors as well.
I tried adding and editing (what I believe to be) the JavaScript theme files in C:\Program Files\pgAdmin 4\web\pgadmin\static\js\Theme to no avail.
